# What do I need to do to have my Raspberry Pi host a webpage with dials indicating CPU temperature, CPU load, etc., in real time?

Tags: unix, apache-http-server, raspberry-pi, gui

I am good with Unix commands and scripting, but I have nearly no web experience. I have a script that grabs metrics I’m interested in, like CPU load or system temp and updates a file every 10 seconds. I would like to point my iPad to a local website hosted by my Raspberry Pi, that has a real-time updating graphical representation of this data.

I’ve worked before setting up a simple Apache web server, and I can write HTML and JavaScript. Besides that, I am lost and need someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad. Do you want some quick and dirty solution, or do you want to code a minimal program which fits on even small Linux embedded systems?

Comment: I initially was looking for something quick and dirty, but the availability of very nice tools mentioned below now has me more interested.

Comment: FYI there's also a Raspberry Pi Stack: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://github.com/firehol/netdata is very easy to set up. Haven't tested it on a Pi though

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I use [Grafana](https://grafana.com) with [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com) for this on my Raspberry Pi 3. They are both relatively easy to setup and connect to each other. They even work well in [Docker](https://www.docker.com) containers on the Raspberry Pi.

I stream all my updates into InfluxDB as they are generated. Then Grafana does all the graphical work of displaying them in a nice visual format. I designed a simple dashboard just for my old iPad with its smaller screen.

It does sound like a lot of installing and overhead, but it sure does look pretty.

[image]

Comment: Very cool. Do you happen to have any screenshots of your Grafana monitors? Just curious.

Comment: Yup. Might not make much sense, this one is a mish-mash of things. Snapped on my computer, so not sized as it looks on the iPad.

Comment: Looks awesome, can't wait to set mine up! I have a 16 node orange pi server that this will be perfect for. Thanks again.

Comment: (off topic) I saw your other question about joining the Pi's together into something that looked like a single board with multiple cores. Was about to send a note that the HPC guy at the college I work at had set up a system but then remembered he was using "son of grid engine" which does not do what you were looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I tried many configs, but I ended up just using Ansible and coding my scripts to explicitly support fragmentation of jobs for farming out to cores. It kept everything as simple as possible with the least amount of overhead. I'm very happy with my $150 64 core mini-server. I benchmark against my university's scientific computing cluster and have been very encouraged. Especially since my electricity consumption is <100 watts on max load. However, each CPU has 256MB RAM available, haha...

Comment: This is not realtime as far as I know? Although the db does collect history for the graphs.

Comment: Agree on "not real-time" in a strict interpretation. Grafana has a refresh interval that can be as small as 1s. Also the original question only inserts data every 10s. I'd ask, in that situation what is "real time". Even websockets would have some sort of refresh interval or push-delay.

Comment: @0xACE Considering its on a pi its a pretty bad idea to be spamming the apache server with requests as well. Also the 10s refers to the askers current setup whereas they want something faster.

Comment: @jdwolf No, it's not. The data that they want to graph comes every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 9):

For having a lightweight and very easy web monitoring dashboard to setup (and extend) monitoring page on your Raspberry you have got [RPi Monitor](https://github.com/XavierBerger/RPi-Monitor).

It comes with some defaults and the configuration is mostly editing a couple of simple text files. I configured it easily to add humidity graphs from a DTH21.

[image: img_link]
[image: img_link2]

Comment: I appreciate the contribution; this seems really lightweight and maybe a nice graphing choice while I learn to setup some of the more involved solutions here. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I have used it for nearly 3 years at home. see related question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/236530/dht21-am2301-sensor-not-measuring-humidity

Answer (score 6):

For realtime applications on the web the best tool is [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). Usually these are implemented in the application server, not the web server, but Apache provides a way to proxy websockets. This could easily provide per second or subsecond updates.

Which library you use on the application server depends on what web platform you want to use, but for example a popular one for Node.js is Socket.IO.

On the client side you can set up a connection like this:

```
socket = new WebSocket("ws://website.net:8282");

socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    var message = event.data;
    // Code to update site
});
```

On the server side with Node.js using the basic WebSocket library:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8282 });
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  dataOnUpdateEvent(function(event) {
    var data = event.getdata();
    var message = parseData(data);
    ws.send(message);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. This is very useful, but looks like a lot of groundwork, which is understandable.

Comment: @jake9115 Heh well your question seemed to suggest you were interested in making this application yourself.

Comment: In all honestly I really was aiming to code it myself, but that grafana is so slick looking that I wouldn't want to reinvent the wheel on this one. Thanks though!

Answer (score 4):

You could also look at Node-RED
https://nodered.org
It comes stock on Raspbian

Here's a dashboard I built
[image]

Comment: I use Node-Red with my setup, but the historical data is only valid as long as your instance is running. That is, if you redeploy (or lose power) none of the historical measurements are kept, your charts all start over from nothing. That feature is what prompted me to start actually logging into InfluxDB.

Comment: Ah, nice to know. Historical data is important to me. I really like how your graphs even incorporate other web-based info, like bitcoin prices. That was beyond my initial scope, but not anymore.

Comment: Yes, that example I even include data from an app I have on the iOS App Store (for Boy Scouts doing good turns) that stores it’s data into google fire base. That’s the map at the bottom. I use node red to pull the data from fire base and push it into influx,so it’s not all influx and grafana.

Answer (score 2):

I use [phpSysInfo](https://github.com/phpsysinfo/phpsysinfo/blob/master/README.md) to monitor all my Linux servers/computers, and I really like how simple it is. The settings are also very easy to understand, and you can set your own refresh rate.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to code in C or C++, you might use some HTTP server library like [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) or [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) to code your specialized HTTP server (perhaps using [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) for database). You then should understand well the [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) protocol (including [HTTP cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) and [HTTP headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)) and [HTML5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5).

You may want to use [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) and [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) techniques (WebSockets are supported by libonion & Wt, Ajax gives ordinary HTTP requests initiated by JavaScript code running in the client browser). You could use HTML5 [canvas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_(GUI)) and/or [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) for graphics. You may find some HTML5 [web frameworks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_framework) 
useful; most of them are using Javascript, DOM, HTML5, ....